# Projecting on Folium a geojson from Highmaps - the coordinates and the size appear incorrect

Tags: python, highcharts, folium

I have downloaded the geojson from [Highmaps](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) for United Kingdom and I see the following information:

```
<Compound CRS: EPSG:7405>
Name: OSGB36 / British National Grid + ODN height
Axis Info [cartesian|vertical]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
- H[up]: Gravity-related height (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: United Kingdom (UK) - Great Britain onshore - England and Wales - mainland; Scotland - mainland and Inner Hebrides.
- bounds: (-7.06, 49.93, 1.8, 58.71)
Datum: Ordnance Survey of Great Britain 1936
- Ellipsoid: Airy 1830
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
Sub CRS:
- OSGB36 / British National Grid
- ODN height
```

I convert the geodataframe to crs 4326 by:

```
import geopandas as gp
uk_highmaps = gp.read_file("path/to/geojson/from/Highmaps")
uk = uk_highmaps.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```

in the scope of projecting in Folium:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[55, 20], zoom_start = 4, control_scale = True)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=uk_highmaps.__geo_interface__,
    fill_color='yellow',
    fill_opacity=0.5,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    name='uk_Highmaps'
).add_to(m)

m
```

And I get this:
[image]

I have tried to work with pyproj.transformer but unsuccessfully. Any ideas how to transform the geodf and project it on the correct coordinates on Folium?